# JpCapWriter crashes JVM

Tags: crash, jvm, writer, jpcap

When I try to use JpCap Writer to save packets to a file, it causes JVM to crash.

Code:

```
captor=JpcapCaptor.openDevice(interfaceList[interfaceNumber], 65535, true, 20);
captor.setFilter("ip and tcp",true);


JpcapWriter writer=JpcapWriter.openDumpFile(captor,"write.txt");
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    Packet packet=captor.getPacket();
    writer.writePacket(packet);
  }
writer.close();
```

Crash info:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f283105953a, pid=3060, tid=139810797537024
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b24
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.11.4
# Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~BufferBlob::jni_fast_GetLongField
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /root/workspace/Sniff/hs_err_pid3060.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Any idea how to solve it? Or any other alternative way to save packets in TCPDump format?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment on my question. I had this same problem and it was caused when I tried to close the writer after it had already been closed. You might be closing it unknowingly. Check your code, and also see what effect removing `writer.close();` has for you.

If you don't need to manipulate the packets, I would recommend using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). It makes it very easy to capture packets as TCPDumps and add capture filters.

Comment: already tried removing writer.close();. Does not prevent the crash.
Is there any other way to store the packets into a file in TCPDump format?

Comment: If you don't need Java for a specific reason (manipulating the packet) I would just use Wireshark or something similar.